# PHP combine values from loop

Tags: php

If I want to display the text as follows in example, how can it be done?

```
$tmp=mysql_query("SELECT ... FROM ....");
$total=mysql_num_rows($tmp);
$tekst1='Your total number of friends are: '.$total.'. Your friends are: ';
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) {
$tekst2=$p['friend'].", ";
}
$text_complete=$tekst1.$tekst2;
echo $text_complete;
```

$text_complete should look like: "Your total number of friends are: 3. Your friends are: John, Mike, Michael". But, using this code above I get "Your total number of friends are: 3. Your friends are: John,"

How can I combine both texts, the one obtained from the loop and the one which is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shoul do like this:

```
       $tmp=mysql_query("SELECT ... FROM ....");
       $total=mysql_num_rows($tmp);
       $tekst1='Your total number of friends are: '.$total.'. Your friends are: ';
       $friends = array();
       while($p = mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) {
             $friends[] = $p['friend'];
       }
       $tekst2= implode(', ', $friends);
       $text_complete=$tekst1.$tekst2;
       echo $text_complete;
```

otherwise you overwrite the variable each time!

EDIT - i corrected the code to use implode as in Xaerxess answer. Previousli i just concatenated and use a substr to remove trailing comma and space

Comment: That's right but you should use it on $tekst1, so you don't need $tekst2 and $text_complete..

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti - I get error message: "Undefined variable: tekst2 on line 25". That line is: "$tekst2.=$p['friend'].", ";"

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti -I found why this happens. Now it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: implode version in other comments is better

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$tekst2 .= $p['friend'].", ";
```

To add to the variable (rather than overwriting it. Then remove the trailing comma:

```
$text_complete=$tekst1. rtrim( $tekst2, "," );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp=mysql_query("SELECT ... FROM ....");
$total=mysql_num_rows($tmp);
$tekst = '';
$tekst='Your total number of friends are: '.$total.'. Your friends are: ';
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) {
$tekst.=$p['friend'].", ";
}
echo $tekst;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tekst2 = new Array();
while($p=mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) {
    $tekst2[] = $p['friend'];
}
$text_complete = $tekst1 . implode(', ',$tekst2);
```

But better would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in sql

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP [implode / join funciton](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.implode.php), so there isn't any trailing comma at the end. In this case:

```php
$fiends = array();
while($p = mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) {
     $friends[] = $p['friend'];
}
implode(', ', $friends);
```

**EDIT:** I basically doubled Billy Moon answer. What's more don't use `mysql_*` functions - they're <strike>deprecated</strike> not recommended - see comments below.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated by whom? Reference?

Comment: @George Cummins: According to [PHP docs](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) `mysql_*` extention isn't developed, isn't recommended by MySQL for new projects, doesn't support all MySQL 4.1+ functionality. 
As it says: _If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use the mysqli extension instead._

Comment: There is a difference between the details you indicated and deprecation. Deprecation is "a status applied to software features to indicate that they should be avoided." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation) The mysql_* functions need not be avoided in suitable circumstances. PDO or mysqli* may be more suitable in some cases, but not all.

Comment: @George Cummins: True, I've used wrong word. I've already edited my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
        $tmp=mysql_query("SELECT ... FROM ....");
        $total=mysql_num_rows($tmp);
        $tekst1='Your total number of friends are: '.$total.'. Your friends are: ';
        while($p=mysql_fetch_array($tmp)) 
           {
           $tekst1 .= $p['friend'].", "; // add friend names from MySQL result.
           }
        $tekst1 = substr($tekst2, 0, -2);//Remove comma.
        echo $tekst1; // Outputs the wanted string
```